# How does one go from convexity to submodularity?

Tags: discrete-geometry, linear-programming, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-eigenvalue

If I have a function which is convex in the hypercube, $[-1,1]^n$ then when would it imply that its restriction to $\{-1,1\}^n$ is submodular?

- It would be helpful is someone can share some specific example calculation! (better if you have examples with spectral norms which is a convex function!)

(..I am implicitly assuming the picture that a function on the Boolean hypercube can always be thought of as a function on the powerset of the set $\{1,2,..,n\}$. The numbers in any element of the powerset specifies the indices of the domain vector which have 1 (and the rest will have -1)...)

Answer (score 1):

Check out page 15 in this paper from 1983:

http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/submodular.pdf

It says that the restriction of a convex function to a binary domain, does not necessarily yield a submodular function.